# Problem running Scala on AS 6

Tags: scala, jboss6.x

I [and others](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/b2f7c56aab23b5da) are having trouble running scala on AS 6.

The problem is a IllegalArgumentException that prevents deployment (stack trace below).

I am trying to run the project generated by the sacalate maven archetype (scalate-archetype-empty) and other projects of mine, all with the same problem.

Is there a known workaround for this?

```
08:41:21,200 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfs:///home/jfaerman/dev/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/scalearn.war state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///home/jfaerman/dev/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/scalearn.war

    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]

   (ommited long trace)

Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error visiting "/home/jfaerman/dev/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/scalearn.war/WEB-INF/lib/scala-compiler-2.8.0.jar/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/NamesDefaults$$anonfun$9.class"

    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:268) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA

    ... 43 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error visiting resource: VFSResourceContext @ scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/NamesDefaults$$anonfun$9.class / BaseClassLoader@10b4adb7{vfs:///home/jfaerman/dev/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/scalearn.war}, visitor: org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.GenericAnnotationVisitor@3f4ddd67

    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.IgnoreSetErrorHandler.handleError(IgnoreSetErrorHandler.java:56) [:1.0.0.GA]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null type

    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:354) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
```

Comment: Scala and Java versions?

Comment: Java is Sun JDK 1.6. Scala i have tried both 2.9.0-1 and 2.8.1, both resulted in the same exception, only differing by the scanned class.

Comment: Just noticed: scala-compiler-2.8.0.jar. Do you need the compiler to be deployed with your application? Well, at least it's maybe something for you to try...

Comment: I also got this error, without the compiler JAR, on scala/Function$$anonfun$untupled$2.class in the 2.8.1 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: in `deployers/scanning-deployers-jboss-beans.xml`, within the `ResourceErrorHandler` bean add a new `<install>` block as follows:

```
 <install method="addIgnored">
     <parameter>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError</parameter>
 </install>
```

Googling also suggested that another workaround was to add an appropriate `jboss-scanning.xml` file, but I couldn't get this to work for my EAR:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/313-restful-cache-with-infinispan.html

Comment: I had the same problem here, and editing `scanning-deployers-jboss-beans.xml` didn't do the trick for me (actually, my `server/default/deployers/scanning-deployers-jboss-beans.xml` in JBoss 6.1.0 already had that `<install>` to ignore `NoClassDefFoundError`). However, it worked after adding a `WEB-INF/jboss-scanning.xml` as mentioned on the page linked in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from matt-r worked for me, but instead of ClassNotFoundException I specified the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` in the /deployers/scanning-deployers-jboss-beans.xml.